# A little problem with a GET request in PHP

Tags: php, get

I have created a simple registration/login system with PHP/SQL in MVC pattern.
It works perfectly but I noticed a little bug; when I login with user and email that they are not in my database, I can't never visualize the warning message "These user and email are not in our database". I noticed that in the http bar on the top I visualize the GET request "action="error" ONLY when then I refresh the page, and not when I immediately click the submit button for the fields control. Where is the problem?

Here my login page code:

```
<h2>Login</h2>

<?php

  $login = new MvcTemplate();
  $login -> loginUserController();

  if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'error'){
          echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">Ops, these user and email are not in our database!</div>';
    }

    if($_GET['action'] == 'captchafail'){
      echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">Ops, flag the Captcha!</div>';
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="La tua Mail" name="mail" required>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="La tua Password" name="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="g-recaptcha my-5" data-sitekey="6LdJAwodAAAAALA5PrlYI9n96h5f4AmSab7SOSKC"></div>
  <div class="d-grid">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Entra</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here the managing of the Login feature in the Controller:

```
// Gestione della funzione di Login;
    public function loginUserController(){

        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
             // Cifratura della password mediante funzione "crypt";
             $securePass = crypt($_POST['password'], '$5$zyPltHmiO9ZqMg7JHRWktNhB_GZ0jiQWvDe0c4N7$');

            $dataController = array(
                'mail' => $_POST['mail'],
                'password' => $securePass
            );

            $responseDb = Data::loginUserModel($dataController, 'users');

            // Controllo di ReCaptcha;
            $secret = '6LdJAwodAAAAAOlQKWxeJ2LCydsRpl1M9SrsXqOZ';
            $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $remoteIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteIP");
                $result = json_decode($verify);

        if($result -> success){


            if($responseDb['email'] == $_POST['mail'] && $responseDb['pass'] == $securePass){

                // Inizializzo una sessione;
                session_start();

                // Creo una variabile di sessione;
                $_SESSION['validation'] = true;

                header('location:users');

            }
        }elseif(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            header('location:captchafail');

        }
        
        else{
                header('location:error');
            }

        }
    }
```

And here the page links.php in the Model directory:

```
<?php

class Pages{

    public static function showPages($links){

        if( $links == 'login' ||
            $links == 'users' ||
            $links == 'update' ||
            $links == 'logout'       
        ){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/'.$links.'.php';

        }elseif($links == 'index'){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/register.php';

        }elseif($links == 'ok'){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/register.php';

        }elseif($links == 'error'){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/login.php';

        }elseif($links == 'captchafail'){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/login.php';

        }elseif($links == 'edit'){

            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/users.php';

        }else{
            
            $moduleNav = 'views/modules/register.php';
        }

        return $moduleNav;

    }
}
```

Comment: `"action="error"` Is that `action="error` in your url? With the quotes `"`?

Comment: Where is the `action` parameter set on the query string?